# Get user information in Crashlytics

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I am using Crashlytics in my application and I wanted to get user id and email along with each crash. I did something like this:

```
Crashlytics.setUserEmail(tokenModel.getEmail());
Crashlytics.setUserIdentifier(String.valueOf(tokenModel.getPk()));
```

I am doing this in my login screen, after the user has provided his email and successfully registered with the app, so as to get user id. The problem is, I am not getting these data in the crash reports.

What is the lifecycle and working of Crashlytics in above context? Do I need to set these fields every time the app opens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure if it needs to be done every time you launch the app and the [Crashlytics docs](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/120548-how-do-i-set-user-information) don't explicitly say it neither.

I know that we do it with every launch and it works - provided user info is displayed properly in the dashboard.

My suggestion would be to try send this information every time you initalize Crashlytics with `Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());`, as soon as you have your user data provided (for example after fetching his user profile from your server).

Answer (score 2):

You need to select the `issue`, click in `more details` and at the top right corner you can see a label with `Identifier`.

You need to set it every time you initialise the Crashlytics. At least doing this it works.

Comment: maybe they changed the UI, there is no "more details", only a "View all sessions", still there is no user identifier...

Comment: After you do "View all sessions", below "Device Statistics", you get the information of user in a small box.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using this `Crashlytics.setUserIdentifier("");` you can check in data tab in firebase. `Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());` working fine.

[image]

Comment: can you please explain that? In Firebase Crashlytics setting of empty user id will remove id from report afaik. How can user email be received (as in your screenshot)?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you look into codes of FirebaseCrashlytics than you can see that userId is being saved into the session. So I am sure that after restarting application your id will be restored.